# Script to list non-Microsoft Services

Tags: windows-services, vbscript, batch-file

Been lookin' for a way to list the non-Microsoft Services to a *.txt file.

Either using vbs or a batch file will be sufficient.

I've tried numerous ways with WMI and the sc.exe command, but can't seem to put my finger on it.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: what makes a service non-microsoft?

Comment: The ones that aren't manufactured by MS ?

Go to MSConfig > Services tab. And check the box at the bottom 'Hide All Microsoft Services'

Answer (score 2):

The [`Win32_Service`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418.aspx) WMI class doesn't have a property that would return the service's manufacturer, but the [`CIM_DataFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387236.aspx) class does. So I can suggest the following solution:

- Query and enumerate the `Win32_Service` class instances.
- In the loop:

  1. Obtain the `PathName` property of the current service (it holds the command line for the service).
  2. Extract the service's file name from the `PathName`.
  3. Obtain the `CIM_DataFile` class instance corresponding to the service file.
  4. Check the file's `Manufacturer` property to find out whether or not the service is Microsoft's. For example, on my Vista box, the `Manufacturer` of all Microsoft services is *Microsoft Corporation*.

**Notes:**

- Some magic may be required when parsing the `PathName` and querying the `CIM_DataFile` class as the `PathName` can include command-line arguments and may not include known file extensions (e.g. *exe*).
- The `Manufacturer` property may be `Null` for some non-Microsoft services.